# Program ouput "15" for no reason?

Tags: c++

I made a program today and when I finally completed it and finished debbuging it, it finally compiles! The name of the people I know appears, and then I have to enter the name of the person I wish to have the number. the thing is, whatever name I input, the programs simply output "15" And I really don,t get why!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int number;
std::string name1;

//int nameAppears()
//{
    //std::cout << "Alex" <<    std::endl;
    //std::cout << "Andre" << std::endl;
    //std::cout << "Guy" <<   std::endl;
    //std::cout << "Grand-ma" <<        std::endl;
    //std::cout << "Grand-pa" <<        std::endl;
    //std::cout << "Jérémy" <<  std::endl;
    //std::cout << "Manon" <<   std::endl; commented this out because it          
    //never worked, I simply put it in main()            
    //std::cout << "Nathalie" <<  std::endl;
    //std::cout << "Stéphanie" << std::endl;
    //std::cout << "Oliver" << std::endl;
//}


std::string enterName()
{
    std::cout << "Enter the name you wish to obtain the number:";
    std::cin >> name1;
    return name1;
}


int link(std::string name1)
{
    if (name1 == "Alex")
        return 9856452535;
    if (name1 == "Andre")
        return 5641598453;
    if (name1 == "Guy")
        return 8459563258;
    if (name1 == "Grand-ma")
        return 8457892653;
    if (name1 == "Grand-pa")
        return 5689852565;
    if (name1 == "Jérémy")
        return 7894521564;
    if (name1 == "Manon")
        return 8453262145;
    if (name1 == "Nathalie")
        return 6589253678;
    if (name1 == "Stéphanie")
        return 5689433645;
    if (name1 == "Olivier")
        return 5695658321;
}


void printNumber (int number)
{
    std::cout << "The number is: " << number << std::endl;
}


int main()
{

    //Make all the names appear
    //nameAppears();
    std::cout << "Alex" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Andre" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Guy" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Grand-ma" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Grand-pa" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Jérémy" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Manon" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Nathalie" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Stéphanie" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Olivier" << std::endl;

    //Get User's input
    std::string name1 = enterName();

    //Link Name to number
    int number = link(name1);

    //Print the desired number
    printNumber(number);
    std::cin.clear(); // reset any error flags
    std::cin.ignore(32767, '\n'); 
    std::cin.get(); // get one more char from the user

}
```

Comment: `int link(std::string name1)` <- This method doesn't return anything if none of the conditions succeed. It should always return something.

Comment: So what should I write instead? Sorry, i'm new to c++ I don't exactly understand

Comment: Add line `return 0;` into the end of the function.

Comment: The horror... why are you not using an `std::map` or even a simple vector of pairs for the name-to-number table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: I originally had just `long`, but see comment thread below for why I've edited this to be `long long` instead.

---

I made a couple changes:

1. Your `link` function doesn't always return a value. I added a `return 0;` at the bottom for the case where none of the names match.
2. Your numbers are too big to fit in an `int`. I switched to using `long long`s everywhere.
3. I did a little minor cleanup (deleted unused code and global variables).

Note that my compiler generated warnings for the first two issues. If yours didn't, consider changing your settings to make sure you see valuable warnings.

The below code works as expected for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string enterName()
{
    std::string name1;
    std::cout << "Enter the name you wish to obtain the number:";
    std::cin >> name1;
    return name1;
}


long long link(std::string name1)
{
    if (name1 == "Alex")
        return 9856452535;
    if (name1 == "Andre")
        return 5641598453;
    if (name1 == "Guy")
        return 8459563258;
    if (name1 == "Grand-ma")
        return 8457892653;
    if (name1 == "Grand-pa")
        return 5689852565;
    if (name1 == "Jérémy")
        return 7894521564;
    if (name1 == "Manon")
        return 8453262145;
    if (name1 == "Nathalie")
        return 6589253678;
    if (name1 == "Stéphanie")
        return 5689433645;
    if (name1 == "Olivier")
        return 5695658321;

    return 0; // if none of the names match
}


void printNumber (long long number)
{
    std::cout << "The number is: " << number << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << "Alex" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Andre" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Guy" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Grand-ma" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Grand-pa" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Jérémy" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Manon" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Nathalie" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Stéphanie" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Olivier" << std::endl;

    //Get user's input
    std::string name1 = enterName();

    //Link name to number
    long long number = link(name1);

    //Print the desired number
    printNumber(number);
}
```

Comment: can't get it to work, for some reason it outputs "-111472192"

Comment: Did you switch to using `long`s everywhere? (`long link`, `printNumber(long`, `long number`)

Comment: nevermind, outputs a different, wrong, negative number for each person

Comment: Actually I copy/paste your code and only changed the numbers that "long link(std::string name1)" to the actual phone numbers of the people in my app

Comment: Try writing a simple program that just does `std::cout << 5689433645L << std::endl;` (replace with your actual numbers; and note the `L`) and see if it prints the correct number. If it does, you have typos somewhere. If it doesn't, then something may be wrong with your compiler.

Comment: @BirdyMcBirdFace Does my code work for you if you *don't* change the numbers?

Comment: Yes your code works if I don't change the numbers. Did the thing you told me, it  outputs the number I wrote but dosen't print the "L"                                           Is that normal?

Comment: @BirdyMcBirdFace So the issue has something to do with the numbers you entered... I imagine you don't want to share them, but can you share something about them? E.g. how many digits, any decimal points or other characters that aren't digits?

Comment: They all have 10 digits, all start with the same 3 digits and there are some "0" in some

Comment: @BirdyMcBirdFace Do any *start* with 0? (That would cause the C++ compiler to interpret them as octals.)

Comment: No but some end with 0

Comment: Try to come up with different (made up) numbers that also cause the issue. It's good practice for debugging, and then perhaps you can share your code with numbers that cause you a problem.

Comment: Found something pretty big! As soon as the number is 10 digits long, it screw up the number and give a wrong one! I tried with 9 digits, works perfectly fine!

Comment: @BirdyMcBirdFace All the examples in my code are 10 digits long, and you said they work.

Comment: @BirdyMcBirdFace It really sounds like you're still using `int`s somewhere instead of `long`s. Do things work if the first digit is a `1`? (The maximum value for an `int` is a little over 2 billion.)

Comment: Found a way to work around that, Since the first 3 numbers are all area codes, I can print "std::cout << the number is: 123 << number << std:endl;" then the phone numbers will become 7 digits long, which solves the strange bug!

Comment: Just revised everything. Only places where I have int is with "int main()" do I have to put long here before "name1" : "long number = link(name1) ??

Comment: `int main` is fine. Yes, `long number = link(name1)`. I thought you copy/pasted my code?

Comment: yeah, I did. Was just making sure everything was normal. Anyway I found a way to work around it, mainly because of you! So honestly thanks a lot dude for your dedication, I was really on the verge of giving up! Thanks :)

Comment: Note that on Windows and most 32-bit systems, `long` isn't any larger than `int`. Use `long long` or better one of the types from `<cstdint>` like `std::int_least64_t`.

Comment: Thanks, @SebastianRedl! That seems likely to be the issue.

Comment: That was indeed the problem! Changed to "long long" and now everything works fine! thanks guys!